# How to call external service on each row and save to jdbc

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

How to call external service on each row in dataframe and save each result to jdbc.

```
df2 = df.map(row -> externalservice.call(row)).cache()

df2.save().format('...')  ... - performs after ALL  'df.rows' has mapped.
```

Wanted save each result after externalservice.call and not wait others.

Want work with spark api save with format.
Do not want work with native jdbc, kafka-producer ...

All researched solutions works with native jdbc or full map with call service.

Answer (score 0):

externalservice must be serializable obj. and need create new instance in each WORKER.